# EntityType 'posts' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My model class is

```
public class posts
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorId;

    public string author_first_name;
    public string author_last_name;
    public string post_text;
}
```

I don't understand why it is saying that. Even though i am following the naming conventions and still have inserted the key annotation for safe measure it is still giving me the error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be with a capital D? Like AuthorID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use Properties, not fields when declaring Entities using EntityFramework.

You should have:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string AuthorFirstName { get; set; }
    public string AuthorLastName { get; set; }
    public string PostText { get; set; }
}
```

When you declare attributes using these Data Annotations they must appear on a public getter.

Give this a whirl and see if it works out for you.